# Extended Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract does not return values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm quite new to Zend and the database classes from it. I'm having problems mapping a Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract to my rows.
The problem is that whenever I try to map it to a class (Job) that extends the Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract class, the database data is not receivable anymore. I'm not getting any errors, trying to get data simply returns null.

Here is my code so far:

Jobs:

```
class Jobs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'jobs';
    protected $_rowsetClass = "Job";

    public function getActiveJobs()
    {       
        $select = $this->select()->where('jobs.jobDateOpen < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()')->limit(15,0);

        $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Job:

```
class Job extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
    public function getCompanyName()
    {
        //Gets the companyName for this row (Is on another table), just for example
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    $oJobs = new Jobs();
    $aActiveJobs = $oJobs->getActiveJobs();
    foreach ($aActiveJobs as $value) {
        var_dump($value->jobTitle);
    }
```

When I remove the "protected $_rowsetClass = "Job";" line, so that the table row is not mapped to my own class, I get all the jobTitles perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `_rowClass` and a `_rowsetClass`. You have `Job` extending `Zend_Db_Row_Abstract` but in your `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` you are setting the `Job` to be the rowset class.

```
class Jobs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'jobs';
    protected $_rowClass = "Job";

    public function getActiveJobs()
    {       
        $select = $this->select()->where('jobs.jobDateOpen < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()')->limit(15,0);

        $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);
        return $rows;
    }
}
```